# What is it that transforms mathematical equations into physical reality?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics

It's clear that mathematics is the language of physics . Mathematics is a tool for constructing many many different realities . Imagine that god decided to create the universe . He used mathematics to design the laws . This is similar to using a programming language to write a program . However , if you write a program in a specific programming language on a piece of paper , Nothing will be done , the program would be useless . You actually need a computer architecture (CPU , physical memory etc ) and an operating system . In order to actually construct the universe , Where and how does god write the reality that he have designed ? In other words , What is it that transforms the fundamental equations (e.g M theory equations or whatever ) into physical reality ?

In response to comments , That's what my research have uncovered . If I was able to invent a new universe mathematically on paper in which intelligent entities of some sort can exist , Have I just discovered some sort of aliens exist in another universe that's actually real or is this universe completely fictional and a sort of mechanism is missing that's is required for making that universe real? If there is no way that I can make certain using physical means that the universe that I've constructed actually exist then it's meaningless to say whether it's real or not . I've actually discovered a mathematically consistent universe that's as real as our universe for take an intelligent being on the other universe he'll too wonder if our universe is real even though he can't do experiments to show that

Comment: Any chance you could share a little bit more about what you've been reading that's made this an interesting or important question to you? What hypotheses have you formed, and what has your research uncovered so far?

Comment: I've added a clarification to my question on what I think . To clarify things more , I think that my line of reasoning (if it makes sense at all) could hint at the possibility that maybe all mathematically consistent universes are as real as each other . There's no need for god to explain why this particular set of laws  and not other set exist etc

Comment: Even if real, what does it matter?  These alternate universes don't interact without ours in any way.

Comment: What? No. Mathematics is the language of numbers and quantity relations. Physics is observation of nature and natural relations. Because of causality, and the conservation of matter and energy in the universe, a precise, formally logical language like mathematics works well for the phenomena physics is concerned with. It's like we're putting a translucent sheet of 'math' over the canon, but largely unreadable, paper of 'nature', and it helps us decode it.

Comment: A computer program is probably unable to completely comprehend the computer it runs on, or the physical world that the computer exists within; your question is similar to a program asking: I know the laws of binary operations, but how are those laws transformed into this reality I exist within? It will never find the answer.